# Show dropdown menu in Angular2 z-index not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I am showing a dropdown menu when the user types in a query into the search bar. The dropdown is loaded on page load and the items are populated by an ngFor loaded in the template. My only issue is the element with a z-index of 9999 is the parent div for the dropdown, it also has a position of absolute but still shows under everything.

Here is the HTML for dropdown menu:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" class="form-inline row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-11 no-padding">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" required ngControl="query" (keyup)="onKey(f.value)">

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-1"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
            <div id="search-suggestions" *ngIf="terms && terms.length > 0">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#term of terms">{{term[0]}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the object:

```
  #search-suggestions {
    border: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;

    ul {
      padding: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 0;

      li {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
        border-radius: $border-radius;
        padding: 5px 10px;

        &:hover {
          background: $gray-lighter;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle or plunker for it?

Comment: Where do you put the CSS?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in a compiled CSS file loaded on the index.html file. I tried even putting it directly on the element to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked the expected CSS landed on the page and the element with the id `search-suggestions` actually exists in the DOM?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the element shows up when I inspect the element with the correct CSS loaded but still shows underneath other elements

Comment: Does the element have the `z-index` value set by CSS? Have you tried with other browsers?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer looks like its fine in Firefox, Safari but not in Chrome...